# Как конвертировать byte в Json?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Есть такой код запроса на сервер.

```
string url = "https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/email/add";

using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    // Создаём коллекцию параметров
    webClient.Headers.Add("PddToken", "token");

    var pars = new NameValueCollection();

    // Добавляем необходимые параметры в виде пар ключ, значение
    pars.Add("domain", "test.ru");
    pars.Add("login", "test");
    pars.Add("password", "tesst");


    var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, pars);

}
```

Сервер возвращает что изображено на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял это byte, ответ же должен быть в json. Как мне с конвертировать ответ в json или сделать запрос, чтобы он в ответ прислал Json.

Comment: Пользуйтесь HttpClient - он сразу позволяет получить строку в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался `string json= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);` Добавил эту строчку и все ок.

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный.